# js regex replace multiple backreferences

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a string based on all matched groups by regex.
I cannot use the $1..$9 backreferences as the number of groups in the regex varies.

Here is a working example with 1 group:

```
string = 'ab ac';
regex = new RegExp( "(^|\\s)(a)", "ig" );
template = "$1<u>$2</u>";
replace = string.replace(regex, template);
```

But this logic doesn't work when there is more than 1 group:

```
string = 'ab bc';
regex = new RegExp( "(^|\\s)(a)|(^|\\s)(b)", "ig" );
template = "$1<u>$2</u>";
replace2 = string.replace(regex, template);
```

What should I use as 'template' to match all groups?

This jsfiddle may make it easier to understand:
https://jsfiddle.net/wfo3n7rs/

Comment: Any reason you can't stick to using two capture groups, ala: [`"(^|\\s)(a|b)"`](https://jsfiddle.net/vugjhLzs/)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe KISS, `"(^|\\s)([ab])"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah, assuming it's only ever single characters like this that works too, and wouldn't for instance ever need to be [`(a|bc)`](https://jsfiddle.net/vugjhLzs/1/).

Comment: @gipadm: How simplified is your example? If the answer posted does not help you, you can make use of a callback function inside the replace method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your regex to:

```
regex = new RegExp( "(^|\\s)([ab])", "ig" );
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jR5wA9/1)**